# How to yield the virtual thread?

Tags: multithreading, project-loom, virtual-threads

- It seems that mysql-connect-java is not compatible with virtual thread. When i use -Djdk.tracePinnedThreads=full, I found some pinned stack trace.
- So my question is how to fix this problem? I have try to replace synchronized to ReentrantLock. But it is still not work.
- So i think another method is to yield the virtual thread to another platform thread.
- I use the springmvc handler to test this scene. spring.threads.virtual.enabled = true. The virtual thread is create like: Thread.ofVirtual().name("testvt").start(task); The source code you can see in tomcat:https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/10.1.x/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/compat/Jre21Compat.java

## My try

```
    public static ThreadPoolExecutor bizPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            4,
            60,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(10000),
            new TaskThreadFactory("mysqlExecPool-"),
            new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    
    public CompletableFuture<List<ResultData>> getDataAsync() {
        CompletableFuture<List<ResultData>> finalRet = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            List<ResultData> result = getData();
            return result;
        }, bizPoolExecutor);
        return finalRet;
    }

    public List<ResultData> getData() {
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String sql = "select * from user where uid=1234";
        List<ResultData> resultDataList = wjt.query(sql, identifyLogRowMapper);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("mysql cost:{} result:{}", end-begin,resultDataList);
        return resultDataList;
    }

    public void mysql30msTestAsync() {
        CompletableFuture<List<MysqlService.ResultData>> data =  mysqlService.getDataAsync();
        try {
            List<MysqlService.ResultData> result = data.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            log.info("mysql30msTestAsync result:{}", result);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            log.error("dataget exMsg:{}", throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
        }
    }
```

## Still problem

- When I stress the program, it still not ok.
- I dump the thread stack by jcmd.
- It seems that virtual thread run into the mysql query logic. That is not my expect.

```
238519          { 
238520            "tid": "8797977",
238521            "name": "TestHelloIServantObj-worker-v-8773083",
238522            "stack": [
238523               "java.base\/java.lang.VirtualThread.parkNanos(VirtualThread.java:631)",
238524               "java.base\/java.lang.System$2.parkVirtualThread(System.java:2648)",
238525               "java.base\/jdk.internal.misc.VirtualThreads.park(VirtualThreads.java:67)",
238526               "java.base\/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:267)",
238527               "java.base\/java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferQueue.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:704)",
238528               "java.base\/java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:903)",
238529               "com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag.borrow(ConcurrentBag.java:151)",
238530               "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162)",
238531               "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:144)",
238532               "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:127)",
238533               "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160)",
238534               "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118)",
238535               "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)",
238536               "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388)",
238537               "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:476)",
238538               "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:486)",
238539               "com.example.loomservlet.service.MysqlService.getData(MysqlService.java:48)",
238540               "com.example.loomservlet.service.MysqlService.lambda$getDataAsync$0(MysqlService.java:56)",
238541               "java.base\/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)",
238542               "java.base\/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$CallerRunsPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2053)",
238543               "java.base\/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:841)",
238544               "java.base\/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1376)",
238545               "java.base\/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.asyncSupplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1782)",
238546               "java.base\/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFuture.java:2005)",
238547               "com.example.loomservlet.service.MysqlService.getDataAsync(MysqlService.java:55)",
238548               "com.example.loomservlet.service.StressTestService.mysql30msTestAsync(StressTestService.java:62)",
238549               "com.example.loomservlet.service.StressTestService.funcDispatch(StressTestService.java:86)",
238550               "com.example.loomservlet.servant.MyFirstServantImpl.testFunc(MyFirstServantImpl.java:62)",
238551               "java.base\/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)",
238552               "java.base\/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)",
238553               "com.huya.taf.server.core.ServantHomeSkeleton.invoke(ServantHomeSkeleton.java:70)",
238554               "com.huya.taf.server.core.TafServerFilterChain.doRealInvoke(TafServerFilterChain.java:25)",
238555               "com.huya.taf.common.AbstractFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractFilterChain.java:38)",
238556               "com.huya.taf.trace.TraceServerFilter.doFilter(TraceServerFilter.java:55)",
238557               "com.huya.taf.common.AbstractFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractFilterChain.java:36)",
238558               "com.huya.taf.server.core.TafServantProcessor.process(TafServantProcessor.java:199)",
238559               "com.huya.taf.net.core.nio.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:95)",
238560               "java.base\/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:311)"
238561            ]
238562          }
238563         ],
238564         "threadCount": "6044"
238565       },
```

Comment: What is `TaskThreadFactory`? Does it create virtual threads? This is not how virtual threads are supposed to be used. They should not be pooled. When you look at your stack trace you will see that the `ThreadPoolExecutor` rejected the task (which means pool and queue are full) and the `CallerRunsPolicy` took place so what was supposed to be asynchronous is not asynchronous.

Comment: I have updated the question. I use the springmvc virtual thread mode to test handle mysql request logic.

Comment: It’s understood that the caller of the `mysql30msTestAsync()` method is a virtual thread. My question was about the thread pool you’re using in your code shown in the question. It’s pointless to use virtual threads, but delegate the actual work to another pool. Even worse, when the configured number of threads in the pool and queue size are too low and jobs run in the caller threads anyway due to the `CallerRunsPolicy`. In other words, some jobs run in the pool’s threads, some are waiting in the queue, and some others run in calling virtual threads.

Comment: @Holger Because the mysql call is not compatible with virtual threads now. So i want to put the mysql-call logic in another platform threads and not pinned the vt carrier thread. This is my idea but it seems also not work. What's your advice?

Comment: @Holger Thanks. Maybe i get your advice. I will change to AbortPolicy and try agin.